# Javax Mail: Unable to connect via pop3 (Command is not valid in this state)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to recive Mails from my server via pop3 by using Javax Mail. I got this error

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Command is not valid in this state.
```

I've tried to change properties but it doesn't change the result. I've checked with another mail client that the server is reachable and password and username is correct so I don't understand why it throws this exception. I tried this:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();

properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "false");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.checkserveridentity", "true");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.required", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");

store.connect(host, port, username, password);
```

The javax.mail log says:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", port 110, isSSL false
S: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
C: USER XXX
S: -ERR Command is not valid in this state.
C: QUIT
S: +OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 POP3 server signing off.
```

Does anyone knows this error or has an idea what to do?

Thanks

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4 and i've added the log above

Comment: Try enabling SSL (see [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/fa3a54e9-de9e-4e94-8b5f-eb96631f56fb/pop3-err-command-is-not-valid-in-this-state?forum=exchange2010))

Comment: Yes, enable SSL.  You've disabled it explicitly, why?  Also, [get a newer version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) if you can.

Comment: When I activate ssl it changes nothing. When I try to use pop3s to force SSL it says javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: After update the version and many tries the connection did it. I had to delete all props without properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true"); and add properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", host); to trust the server anyway.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method `Session.getInstance(properties, null)` you may have to pass a third parameter that some server needs.

```
Session.getInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                    })
```

And you should try to use `Store store = session.getStore("pop3")` with `Store store = session.getStore("pop3s")`